# Automatic type conversions in the implementation only

Tags: c++, oop, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

1. Two classes: `Processor` and `Data`.
2. `Data` represents some data object the user can pass to `Processor`'s public methods.
3. Internally, `Processor` needs to use `InternalData` type which is based on `Data`.
4. I made private conversion functions from `Data` to `InternalData` and back inside `Processor` to avoid repeating code and localize changes required when `Data`'s interface would change someday.
5. But I'd like these conversions to be implicit in `Processor` instead of explicit.
6. These conversion functions are only for `Processor` implementation's use.
   Shouldn't be visible nor accessible from the outside world.
7. `InternalData` is a library type. I don't have control over it and I cannot modify its interface.
   That is, I cannot just add converting constructors or conversion operator member functions to them.
   You can consider it to be built-in type if you wish.
8. I don't want to put those converters inside `Data` class either, since it's not its business and it shouldn't know that `Processor` converts it to something else internally.

Long story short, I'd like the `Processor`'s implementation to know how to make type conversions between `Data` and `InternalData` implicitly, but no one else except `Processor` should be able to do it or even know about it being done inside `Processor`'s implementation.

Is there any way to do it in C++?

**My attempts at solution**

My first attempt was to make converting constructor and conversion operator inside of `Data`, making them `private`, and making the `Processor` a `friend` of `Data` to be able to access those private converters. But this does more than I want: it gives `Processor` *full access to `Data`'s internals*, which is bad.

Then I noticed that this bunch of functions (converters) together make kind of an *interface* of `Data`, but an interface which should be only for `Processor`'s use. So I made an abstract base class `InternalDataConversions` and declared these conversion functions there, as `pure virtual`. I made this class a `friend` of `Processor`. Then I made the `Data` class to derive from it privately, and implemented these converters. This way `Processor` can use this "conversion interface" internally, but it cannot access anything else inside `Data`, which is better.
But the downside is that now `Data` class needs to specify in its definition something which it shouldn't care of, and it unnecessarily makes it depend on `InternalData` and `InternalDataConversions`, which is ugly.

Any better ideas?

Comment: TL;DR; Prose is nice for grammar and poetry courses. Programming language questions at least require to give some pseudo code. Sorry I cannot (don't want to) read this. (Even a simple appropriate UML diagram would tell more than 1000 words).

Comment: If you don't like reading, go somewhere else. There's no requirement of answering everyone. Code would be just that: code. It won't tell you what I need of it, and what are the restrictions of my design.

Comment: Just put in my 2cents of criticism (can you bear it?), didn't downvote ...

Answer (score 0):

You can provide conversion member functions in `InternalData`. A copy constructor can take a `Data`, and a conversion operator can produce one back.

```
class InternalData
{
public:
    InternalData(const Data & data);
    operator Data() const;
};
```

Presumably `InternalData` is private to `Processor` and so this won't clutter up the interface.

Comment: I added a clarification that `InternalData` is not under my control. It is a library type, used internally inside `Processor`. So I cannot simply add another constructor to it, nor conversion member function. I need to do these conversions outside of it somehow, but inside the `Processor` class.

Comment: @SasQ is `Processor` under your control? If so you can have it use a class derived from `InternalData` which adds the methods.

Comment: Yes, `Processor` is under my control, as well as `Data`. Thanks for the hint. `InternalData` is just some system-defined `struct`, so perhaps I could derive from it, as you proposed. Though I wonder what if this were some "not for deriving" library type such as those from STL, or a built-in type...